# When does the minimum temperature in a four-stroke cycle occur inside the engine cylinder?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, engines

I've checked on quite a few places on the net and some say it occurs at the beginning of suction stroke and others say at the end of suction stroke. I believe it to be at the end of suction stroke because after exhaust some of heat absorbed by cylinder from combustion products remains and when suction is completed, the fresh charge will absorb some of that remaining heat thereby making the cylinder cooler. I'd like an explanation with graphs(ACTUAL T-S diagram, if possible would be much appreciated) and also citation of some credible sources if possible. I've uploaded a T-S diagram for SI engine but this is the ideal T-S diagram which like ideal P-V diagram(of otto cycle) misses the portion where scavenging and actual suction occurs after the expansion of remaining gases that remain at the end of exhaust stroke(this difference is clear from other two images of ideal and actual P-V diagrams). Also I'd like to know if there is any difference between its occurrence(the minimum temperature timing) in S.I and Diesel engines.
[image: T-S diagram of an SI engine.]

[image: Ideal P-V diagram of SI Engine]
[image: Actual diagram of SI Engine.]

Lastly this question is a multiple choice question of an exam with options:-
a) End of exhaust stroke    b) end of suction stroke    c) Beginning of suction stroke     d) beginning of exhaust stroke

Comment: It may occur at different spots in the cycle for different engines, or even for the same engine in different operating conditions.  It'd also be a hard thing to measure, if you're going after the temperature of the charge, separate from the temperature of the cylinder walls.

Comment: I've edited the question and mentioned in the end(after diagrams) the four options available for the question. This should make it specific for you to answer.

Comment: Where are you drawing the boundary? Is the cylinder wall included? What about the top of the piston? Or all of the piston? How much heat can the charge absorb during the induction part of the cycle? How much will the cylinder wall or piston change in temperature?

Comment: Let's say everything that comes into contact with he charge, i.e cylinder wall, piston top/head, valves etc are included in the boundary. Although I don't see how the amount of heat absorbed by the charge and change in temperature of wall or piston are relevant because these quantities are relative, I mean if there is certain amount of heat residing in engine parts and then some absorbed by the charge, it's gonna be same in every cycle of combustion. And temperature still seems to be lowest(relative to other points in cycle) in the beginning or end of suction.

Comment: Even if we increase fuel thus increasing amount of heat in engine, the temperature after heat absorption by charge seems to decrease as compared to temperature during the rest of the cycle, so it still should be at its lowest.